# Charts.js with PHP/MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I am using the charts.js within my project (http://www.chartjs.org/)

I want to show a chart showing the download count for each of the last 12 months.

You can see the datetime in my database, how do I go about this?

This is my js

```
<!----- CHARTS / DOWNLOADS ----->
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("downloads");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Downloads',
            data: [12, 23, 45, 65, 67, 87, 123, 342, 123, 342, 256, 467],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(246, 10, 36, 1)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(246, 10, 36, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is my Database

```html
2 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL NULL 2017-02-10 13:30:13 3 2904395385 NULL
3 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 13:31:06 3 2904395385 NULL
4 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 13:36:23 3 2904395385 NULL
5 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 13:59:58 3 2904395385 NULL
6 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 14:04:02 3 2904395385 NULL
7 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 14:05:31 3 2904395385 NULL
8 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 14:48:35 3 2904395385 NULL
9 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 14:50:43 3 2904395385 NULL
10 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 14:51:55 3 2904395385 NULL
11 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 14:53:33 3 2904395385 NULL
12 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 14:55:20 3 2904395385 NULL
13 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 15:08:08 3 2904395385 NULL
14 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 15:12:28 3 2904395385 NULL
15 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 15:14:43 3 2904395385 NULL
16 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL Brad Fletcher 2017-02-10 15:16:02 3 378143228 NULL
17 Sdm4HhcSIDhC twitter NULL Brad Fletcher 2017-02-10 16:40:48 5 378143228 NULL
18 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL Deep House 2017-02-10 18:48:44 3 2886815776 NULL
19 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL Deep House 2017-02-10 18:50:32 3 2886815776 NULL
20 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL Deep House 2017-02-10 19:14:56 3 2886815776 NULL
21 YE1lHiWApOYN twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 19:27:19 3 2904395385 85.255.235.6
22 sJ8UcXChXOXh twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 19:53:44 3 2904395385 85.255.235.6
23 sJ8UcXChXOXh twitter NULL Deep House 2017-02-10 20:11:00 3 2886815776 85.255.235.6
24 sJ8UcXChXOXh twitter NULL World Trade Forums 2017-02-10 20:38:13 3 2904395385 85.255.235.6
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: I'm looking fo rthe best way to pull the data from the database and display it in the chart using PHP.